# OleDb connection to excel file at sharepoint doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I have in my VBA code connection string pointing to the workbook itself, e.g.:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _ 
 "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _ 
 "Persist Security Info=False;" & _
 "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes"
```

It works well when the file is stored at local, but after it's uploaded to a Sharepoint space, it no longer works due to connection failure ("Connection could not be established!").

Any idea to get it working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the value of Thisworkbook.fullname?

Comment: It's a long http url to the workbook on sharepoint, http://.../.../effort.xlsm.

Answer (score 1):

Not much detail here which leaves a lot of assumptions to be made...but here goes...

A bit of googling shows that there are lots of Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB errors with Access; you make not mention of Access so, that could be your issue right there - wrong connection type.

Since your connection is "to the workbook itself" the easy solution is to refernce the cells via a simple XL function.

In our environment, (Office 2007, SP 2007) it is worth noting that connections typically contain a connection string: "Provider=Microsoft.Office.List.OLEDB.2.0").  Again, probably the wrong connection string.

Try storing the spreadsheet in SP first, open the file (checked out of course), then create the connection.

If all else fails, I like the "record macro then fix the code" method!